# Unwanted space between divs - HTML, CSS

Tags: css, whitespace, html

I have searched through the forums and good old google and have found many answers but non seem to work on my page. 
Anyway here is the question,

I have 2 divs that are positioned side by side, and I wish to get rid of the whitespace

www.blisshair.com.au/test.html :(http://www.blisshair.com.au/test.html)

I want to the black from the "link 1" to join to the main content in the center,

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thank you.

EDIT: Tried opening in Internet explorer 8 and it seems top exactly how I want it, besides the 2 bottom divs not lining up, 
Is it possible to do this with an UL and SPAN tags ? I am aiming for a tabbed look, for example, when you click on link 2, the background around link 2 goes black and the black color "flows" into the main content page, sorry if this doesnt make sense, early AM here :D

Thanks again

Comment: They are not side by side. Which browser are you opening it in?

Comment: you can make the background colour of all cells black, although in general it is considered bad practise to construct a menu like that from a table

Comment: I do not see them side by side in Firefox 3.6.13.

Comment: In firefox 3.6.13 they are side by side, as well as IE, but the resoltion of my monitor is 1680 * 1050, maybe that has something to do with it? Will view it from laptop when i get to work this morning, thanks :)

Comment: 1200*1024 or something here, that could be it... odd.

Comment: Please open one question for each isolated question, rather than editing them into here. When you think someone has answered this question mark that reply as answer, and if you have other questions open new questions for it - rather than keeping editing new items into this.

Comment: When you have code to demonstrate, paste it somewhere online instead of linking us to the hosted version.  I can't even see the page anymore.

Answer (score 3):

For starters: don't use tables in a non-semantic manner, and don't use inline styles when you can avoid it.

You've got a list of links, so put your links in a list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="...">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">Link 3</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The problem you're having is that you only put the class that produces the background color (`menu1`) on the first item in your table.

You should give your parent item a class or id instead:

```
<ul id="nav">...
```

And then give the *entire* nav a background color (You'll also have to remember to get rid of the default padding and margin on the nav):

```
#nav
{
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahh i see, the only reason I added the table was it is the only way I could figure out to get the menu and content page to "connect" so it seems like tabs. If you open in IE, that is exactly what I want to acheive(besides the divs not lining up on the top...), is this possible using an UL and SPAN in firefox? Sorry if this doesnt make sense, am half asleep :) Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I assume you want the "tabs" to go horizontally, which just means you need to style the `li` elements with `float: left;` of course that brings on the whole issue of floating, which takes a while to understand properly.

Comment: Don't float them, use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`. (This last one will only work on IE7 for naturally inline elements... `li` is naturally a block element.)

Comment: @ANeves `inline-block` isn't supported in IE6, but floating is. You'd also have to remove white-space between elements as well. @Nikalas Haufe,  You just need a solid understanding of [flow control](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control)

Comment: @zzzzBov IE6, really?? It's from 2001... encumbering yourself for a browser that doesn't even respect CSS2 is doing a disservice to the internet. (Also, ROI.) About displaying inline, that **is** what you are doing with the floats - except less semantically. And with float you often need to clear them afterwards by using an extra and empty item inside the parent container (to stretch the background, etc). Call me a purist if you must, but I fail to see how floating things to display them as inline is proper.

Comment: @ANeves, I usually don't support IE6, but floats aren't as bad as everyone seems to make them out to be. I'd rather deal with clearing a float than having to worry about dropping all whitespace between inline-block elements. As for semantics: semantics are in the Content not in the style. You shouldn't ever need to add a `clearfix` to clear floats (there are some rare exceptions, in which case I'd favor `inline-block`). I'm not sure that IE7 supports inline-block, and IE7 was released in 06.

Comment: IE7 supports inline-block only for elements that are naturally inline: it works for `span`/`code`/etc but not `li`/`div`/etc. Don't you have to "clearfix" if you use a top-horizontal menu? If you have a menu with a variable size, you do - otherwise you risk getting content to the right of the menu if it's last line is too small. (YMMV) Doesn't matter too much anyway, and we're getting off-topic.

Comment: `clearfix` is adding an *additional* element to clear content that should be cleared with elements already in the display order. Adding a `clear` style to an element already in the DOM is *not* a `clearfix`. The simplest trick is to float the parent, and add a `clear` style on whatever comes after it.

Answer (score 1):

You might check into css resets like here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Basically, browsers will default to have margins or padding between div elements or elements that have their own 'block' (h1, h2, and several others).

You'll need to set margin and padding levels to zero, as a starter.

Comment: CSS resets, booo! When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. :( Example: are you comfortable with not having margins on your headers?

Comment: "are you comfortable with not having margins on your headers?" - I'm comfortable overriding the different defaults between browsers. A reset is simply a starting point, not a finished style...

Answer (score 1):

Zounds!

[Is this a solution?](http://jsfiddle.net/L4tYp/) Certainly seems so!

Quick and dirty:

- Float the menu left and give it 100px width;
- Use a left margin for the content, do not float it;
- Use background color on a container of both the menu and the content;
- Realize how much trouble you're going to have if this was a problem already;
- Persevere, that is to say *DO NOT GIVE UP*, no one was born knowing it! :)

The harder it is, the more you'll learn. Expect a lot of learning. :)

The HTML:

```
<h1 id="header"><a href="#"><img src="FancyHairLogo.png" alt="ZOMG PURTY HAIR" /></a></h1>
<div id="textContainer">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>WELCOME TO BLISS HAIR EXTENSIONS!</h2>
        <p>
            this is the homepage of bliss hair extebnsions, please check back soon as we are contionously updating the content on this page!
        </p>
        <p> etc ... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #666;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#header a img {
    border: dashed 1px gray;
}

#textContainer, #header * {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

### Issues

- "The title's top will not line with the menu's top!"

  - Yes, because adjoining borders collapse and the bigger applies.
  - Use a css rule like `content>h2:first-child { margin-top: 0px; }` to quickly hack it away, but make sure to **understand** what is happening, it will save you braincells and time in the future.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! I will definately read up alot more on CSS, alot has changed since I last made a website, lol, thanks again!